# Perl threads not printing correctly

Tags: multithreading, perl, file-io, printing

If there are explicit examples in another post please let me know.  I am having problems with interleaved printing from my threads.  I am trying to control my threads by using a shared variable across all threads.  The pseudo code below highlights the pieces of my code giving me problems.  I have tried everything to make the threads wait their turns to print.  Right now only a few output lines are being destroyed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                                                                
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my $PRINTFLAG :shared = 1;

Run_Threads();

sub Do_stuff{

    lock($PRINTFLAG);
    cond_wait($PRINTFLAG) until $PRINTFLAG == 1;
    $PRINTFLAG = 0;
    print "$working\n";
    $PRINTFLAG =1;
}
```

Sub to spawn threads.

```
sub Run_Threads{

    my @threads;

    for (my $i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){
        push @threads, threads->create(\&Do_stuff);
    }

    foreach (@threads){
        $_->join;
    }
}
```

Comment: Anytime I hear "threads" and "not printing correctly" in the same sentence I start feeling a sense of dread. This is generally a hard thing to do properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would seem that each thread has its own handle, and thus its own output buffer. Considering that Perl file handles can't be shared using the mechanisms in [threads::shared](http://p3rl.org/threads%3a%3ashared), that's not very surprising.

That means you need to flush the handle's buffer before releasing the lock. You can do that explicitly:

```
select->flush();       # Flush handle currently default for print.
```

Or you can have perl flush automatically after every print to that handle:

```
select->autoflush(1);  # Autoflush handle currently default for print.
$| = 1;                # Autoflush handle currently default for print.
```

Note: To use the `->flush` and `->autoflush` methods (but not for `$|=1;`) before Perl 5.14, you'll need to also load [IO::Handle](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aHandle).

---

By the way,

```
my $PRINTFLAG :shared = 1;
lock($PRINTFLAG);
cond_wait($PRINTFLAG) until $PRINTFLAG == 1;
$PRINTFLAG = 0;
print "$d\n";
$PRINTFLAG =1;
```

can be simplified to

```
my $PRINTMUTEX :shared;
lock($PRINTMUTEX);
print "$d\n";
```

Comment: $PRINTFLAG isn't a filehandle.  I am just trying to use it to stall a thread while one finishes printing to standard out.  Do I need to print to a file handle?  Is internal buffering screwing me over?  Should I set a buffer to zero?

Comment: @zev.kronenberg, Re "$PRINTFLAG isn't a filehandle", I know.

Comment: @zev.kronenberg, Re "Do I need to print to a file handle?" I imagine so, because you're asking for our help to do it. ?!?!

Comment: @zev.kronenberg, Re "Is internal buffering screwing me over?" Sorry that wasn't clear?!

Comment: @zev.kronenberg, Re "Should I set a buffer to zero?" That makes no sense, and I told you what you should do.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  by setting $| = 1; My problems were solved.  This would haven been the last place I looked.  Out of curiosity why is the buffer screwing up printing to STDOUT?

Comment: @zev.kronenberg, "It would seem that each thread has its own handle, and thus its own output buffer."

Comment: Hmm.  By a glance at 5.14.2's `threads.c` and some minimal testing, it appears that the end of the thread's start routine flushes all of that thread's filehandles.

Comment: @pilcrow ah yes I am in the dark ages at 5.10

Comment: @zev.kronenberg, hmm, source inspection of 5.10 suggests the same behavior.  `$|` is often prescribed as penicillin when the patient says, "My output hurts!"  I'm glad it worked.  However, my friend, no version of your question executes correctly, much less reproduces your symptoms.  (Indeed, as currently written the arguments to `->create` ensure that *zero* threads are spawned.)  Something else may be amiss with your actual code.

Comment: A note for @posterity, ikegami has edited the post *post hoc* to fix the broken `->create()` call...

Answer (score 3):

From my experience with threads it's much better/simple to use [Threads::Queue](http://perldoc.perl.org/Thread/Queue.html).

I have two queues: one for the tasks for running threads and another for the results from threads.

So in my master thread I just check the result's queue and print from it. So no any conflicts accessing result file etc.